# Executing a homemade shell script inside a C program

Tags: c, shell, sh

I have a "test.sh" script and i need to run it inside a C program. Both files are in same folder. I've seen that people paste script code inside C program using #Define. I wonder if i can call that script without doing that. I'm looking for some function like "Call(test.sh)" inside C to execute and return the script. Any ideas?

Test script code:

```
 echo "Hi, you're printing me from C program"
 exit 1
```

Sorry, was kinda distracted! I'm working in ubuntu. I've done several scripts before and i need that script to re-execute my C program after it ends. I'm developing a simple game and i need the script to re-execute my program to play again without closing my terminal. Is this better clear? I'm doing it this way right now but is not working:

```
int main(){
 system("test.sh");
 return 0;
}
```

terminal says:
     " sh: 1: test.sh: not found"

Comment: Are you on a system which have a shell that can execute the commands? Then what have you tried? How did your attempt work, or not work? Can you please to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and show us?

Comment: I've just edited my question, please take a look again!

Comment: First find out how to run your script from the terminal, then use that same command in your call to `system`

Comment: Well i do know how to do it, but i don't know how to use command "bash test.sh"  inside a C program... that's why i'm asking

Comment: Is `test.sh` in the correct location? Is it marked executable? Does it have a [*shebang*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))? If you make the path to it (in the program) absolute, make it executable and add a shebang, does it work then?

Comment: @FrankPonte You just put any shell command in the string you pass to `system`, e.g.  `system("bash test.sh");`

Comment: Yes, i've just realize that what you write inside a system() function works exactly as writing it on terminal line! Thank you very much to every1 who gave me ideas: system("bash test.sh") just did the job!!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
system("./test.sh");
```

And make sure the file is executable and exists at the specified path. The above works only if the file is in the **current working directory**.

Comment: And what if the script is not in the current working directory of the process? `.` doesn't mean the same directory as the executable.

Comment: Right `.` - current working directory. Note necessarily the one of the executable.